# How to nest multiple keydown events?

Tags: jquery

My overall goal is to be able navigate between 3 divs each having CSS id's of #sectionA, #sectionB, and #sectionC using TAB keyboard key . And within each div, I have an unordered list I would like to use the right and left arrow keys to navigate through the list.

My HTML markup is this:

```
               <div id="sectionA">
            <ul id="ul_sectionA">
                    <li> Section A -  Test B</li>
                    <li> Section A -  Test B</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="sectionB">
            <ul id="ul_sectionB">
                    <li> Section B -  Test B</li>
                    <li> Section B -  Test B</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
            <div id="sectionC">
            <ul id="ul_sectionC">
                    <li> Section C -  Test B</li>
                    <li> Section C -  Test B</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

So far, I was able to get the following jquery code but not working once I add the second $(document).keydown(function() code.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var divs = ["sectionA","sectionB","sectionC"];
        var startIndex = 0;

        $(document).keydown(function(e)
        {
            alert("test");
                if (e.which == 9)
            {
                 $("div").css("border", "");
                    $("#"+divs[startIndex]).css("border","1px solid blue");
                var divID = $("#" +divs[startIndex]).attr("id");
                $(document).keydown(function(event)
                {
                    if(event.which == 37)
                    {
                        if("#"+divID+"ul li").addClass() == "highlight")
                        {
                            $(this).next().addClass("highlight");
                        } else
                        {
                            $(this).addClass();   
                        }
                    }
                });
                startIndex++;

                    if(startIndex === divs.length)
                    {
                            startIndex = 0;                  
                    }
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why are you nesting? Refactor so the functionality all resides in one event...

Comment: never heard of refactor. is there a working example

Comment: Refactor, as in re-organize, re-code, re-design. Use variables to track which tab and list item you're on; Then based on which tab is active, select various list items within that tab based on the arrow key used.

Comment: [code refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

Comment: thanks, I have to read more on Refactor

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction. It is not perfect by any means.

The basic problem you had was trying to nest a keydown event. You just can't do that. Instead you will need to have a separate keydown event for the right and left arrows, each of those events will need to figure out which div the user has "selected" and then scroll through those list items in that div. The code below will start that process, but it only handles the left arrow and even that is not complete yet.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var divs = ["sectionA","sectionB","sectionC"];
        var startIndex = 0;
        var startListItemIndex = 0;
        var divID;
        $(document).keydown(function(e)
        {
            if (e.which == 9)
            {

              $("div").css("border", "");

              $("#" + divID + " ul li").css("border", "0px"); //remove all borders 
              $("#"+divs[startIndex]).css("border","1px solid blue"); //now add border to selected div
              divID = $("#" +divs[startIndex]).attr("id");

              startListItemIndex = 0; //reset startIndex each time tab is pressed. 
              startIndex++;

              if(startIndex === divs.length)
              {
                      startIndex = 0;                  
              }

            }
              //left arrow click
              if(event.which == 37)
              {
                startListItemIndex++; 

                //remove all highlights first
                 $("#" + divID + " ul li").removeClass("highlight");

                //now add highlight to the next li element. 
                $("#" + divID + " ul li:nth-child(" + startListItemIndex + ")").addClass("highlight"); 
               }
        });


    });   
  </script>
```

Comment: Why 2 keydown events bound? Just include an else if statement in the first.